# jQuery can't find() inside a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm very new to jQuery and i'm developing a plugin (for my own use) for setting DOM elements `html()` with content returned by an ajax call. Example:

```
<span id="a" class="scalar">?</span>
<span id="b" class="scalar">?</span>
<span id="c" class="scalar">?</span><!-- this will not be updated -->
```

If `stats.php` is going to return a JSON object like this: `{ a : 3, b : 7 }` the resulting HTML would be (each object property will match an `id` among the selection on which the plugin was invoked):

```
<span id="a" class="scalar">3</span>
<span id="b" class="scalar">7</span>
<span id="c" class="scalar">?</span><!-- this will not be updated -->
```

This is the plugin invocation and definition. **Question** is: why `find()` can't properly select the element to be updated?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.scalar').scalar({ url : '../REST/stats.php' });
   });
</script>

(function($) {

    $.fn.scalar = function(options) {

        var opt = $.extend({
            url : 'REST/stats.php',
            type : 'POST',
            context: this,
            dataTypeString : 'json'
        }, options);

        $.ajax($.extend(opt, {
            success : function(obj) {
                for(k in obj) {
                    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
                    console.log(this.find('#' + k));
                }
            }
        }));

        return this.each();
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for descendant elements, and the elements you are looking for are not descendants (they are all siblings of each other). Use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
console.log(this.filter('#' + k));
```

`this` will be a jQuery object wrapping a set of DOM elements. Unless one or more of those elements contains a descendant element with the `id` you are looking for with `find`, it won't work. You need to look at the elements themselves, which is what `filter` does.